# #Angular 2 #razor views #asp.net #mvc

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I use angular 2 and razor views to get to

```
<my-component [items]= @Model.Items ></my-component>
```

Model is a Mvc.net.

I am using typescript. Component templates are inline and not using template url

At help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can't easily do this. This was something you could do with Angular1.

Use Asp.net WebAPI to expose your models to your Angular app through a stateless Rest API service instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `    
<h2>My favorite skill is: {{myskills}}</h2>
<p>Skill:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let skl of skills">
    {{ skl }}
  </li>
</ul>
`
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'ASP.NET MVC 5 with Angular 2';
    skills = ['MVC 5', 'Angular 2', 'TypeScript', 'Visual Studio 2015'];
    myskills = this.skills[1];
}
```

http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/
And checkout [this link](https://github.com/mithunvp/ng2Mvc5Demo) for the github project per the link above.